# Como trabalhar com gerenciamento de conflitos no merge de branches?

Tags: git, merge

Dei uma estuda rápida no git-flow, porém, não identifiquei como este trabalha a questão dos conflitos de merge. Em um artigo que li, o autor mencionava de cada colaborador puxar o repositório, gerenciar os conflitos e somente depois subir seu código.

Como proceder neste caso?

Comment: Essa pergunta é boa. A ideia que tenho que é que o problema(conflito) seja "distribuído" para cada desenvolvedor.
O que normalmente acontece é que regularmente cada desenvolvedor atualiza sua branch, fazendo um merge, com a branch que ele pretende fazer o merge.
Se eu estou trabalhando na tarefa A, cuja branch também se chama A, e ao termina-la pretendo fazer um merge com a branch B(outras pessoas tambem vao fazer merge para B), regularmente eu faço o merge de A com B e resolvo os conflitos que aparecerem. E quando for de fato subir A para B, a chance de conflito é bem baixa.

Comment: Particularmente, nunca li nada sobre preocupação explícita do git-flow com os conflitos de mesclagem. Minha prática diz que isso é eventual (não é a coisa mais comum do mundo) e que é resolvido em grande parte a nível de `pull/merge-request`. Também não tive uma boa experiência com a resolução distribuída entre os membros da equipe: cada um resolvia de qualquer jeito para dar continuidade à sua tarefa, de modo a prejudicar o trabalho dos outros

Answer (score 1):

Depois do seu commit você vai fazer o Push e criar o merge request (juntar a sua branch com o master), caso haja o conflito:

> Grupo que possui um chefe de arquitetura (ou alguem que gerencie o
>   projeto) essa pessoa vai ficar responsável por resolver os conflitos.
>
> Grupo com desenvolvedores indepedentes, após o merge request e exista
>   o conflito, cada desenvolvedor precisa resolver os conflitos individualmente.

Exemplo:

Primeiro dê um pull na ultima versão do master e em seguida volte para sua branch.

```
git merge origin Master
```

corrija os conflitos...

```
 <<<<<<< HEAD
public void exemplo() {
}
=======
public void exemplo(string teste) { ...
}
>>>>>>> origin/<remotebranch>
```

você precisa remover o que não sera usado.

essa parte vem do Master:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
 public void exemplo() {
 }
 =======
```

e essa parte vem da sua branch

```
=======
public void exemplo(string teste) { ...
}
>>>>>>> origin/<remotebranch>
```

após editar, faça o commit e push novamente.

Comment: Para essas correções, pode utilizar o [mergetool](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mergetool)

Comment: eu prefiro corrigir via ide, tenho mas controle sobre o que vai ser mesclado. (Visual Studio) @ValdeirPsr